# Swift combine - return Future conditionally

Tags: arrays, swift, combine

I have a function with return type Future<Void, Error> that returns and saves items from an API

What I'm hoping to do is check whether the items array returned is empty and if so make a call to another service endpoint to receive / save items

Obviously the second call needs to happen conditionally and after the first has completed

I've found examples using flatMap that seem very close to what I want but these use AnyPublisher rather than Future and trying with Futures seems to yield me strange return types

You can probably tell I only know the fundamentals of combine! If it was simple I would convert these calls to async await and make a conditional call to the alternative endpoint but combine is used throughout the network and API layers and if possible hope to do it with the established combine pattern

If anyone has a skeleton example of returning conditional futures from a function I'd be very grateful (example of current function below)

Thanks!

```
    func sync() -> Future<Void, Error> {
    return Future { [weak self] promise in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        strongSelf.service.getItems
            .receive(on: strongSelf.scheduler)
            .sink {
                if case .failure(let error) = $0 {
                    promise(.failure(error))
                }
            } receiveValue: { items in
                 // if items empty make another api call
                strongSelf.saveItems(items)
               
                promise(.success(()))
            }.store(in: &strongSelf.subscriptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: getItems is a Future?

Comment: Yeah the API endpoints are all Future<>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the challenges here is the fact that subscribing to a publisher is a synchronous operation.  Your `Future`, as written, is going to execute from top to bottom and end.  The subscription you create with `sink` is going to fall out of scope immediately, and be cancelled.

One sneaky way to get around this is to capture the subscription in the closure and dispose of it manually:

```
func sync(service: Service) -> Future<[Int], Error> {
    Future<[Int],Error> { contination in
        var subscription: AnyCancellable?
        subscription = service.getItems()
            .flatMap { items in
                if items.isEmpty {
                    return service.generateItems().eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    return Just(items).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }.sink {
                if case .failure(let error) = $0 {
                    contination(.failure(error))
                }
                subscription?.cancel()
            } receiveValue: {
                contination(.success($0))
                subscription?.cancel()
            }

    }
}
```

Here the subscription is captured in the sink's closure as an `AnyCancellable?` variable.  This prevents it from being released (and cancelled) when the future's closure ends. The subscription must be cancelled, in the sink, in every success and failure case.

I assumed that your API calls, like `service.getItems()`, return a `Future`. The `flatMap` converts the results that call into a new publisher.  If the `getItems()` call returns an empty array, then the publisher created by `flatMap()` is the one returned by `generateItems()` (another API call I invented).  If the `getItems` call is not empty, then I use `Just` to provide a publisher that simply returns the items (with some decoration of operators to make the data types line up).

For this example, I made up a service that looks like this:

```
class Service {
    var shouldReturnItems: Bool;

    init(shouldReturnItems: Bool) {
        self.shouldReturnItems = shouldReturnItems
    }

    func getItems() ->Future<[Int], Error> {
        Future<[Int], Error> { continuation in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now().advanced(by: .seconds(1))) {
                if self.shouldReturnItems {
                    continuation(.success([1, 2, 3, 4]))
                } else {
                    continuation(.success([]))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func generateItems() -> Future<[Int], Error> {
        Future<[Int], Error> { continuation in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now().advanced(by: .seconds(1))) {
                continuation(.success([5, 6, 7, 8]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also solve this problem using Swift Structured Concurrency.  You don't have to "convert" any of the calls as Combine does that already.  You can still preserve the `Future` based interface for callers that don't want to use async/await:

```
func sync(service: Service) -> Future<[Int], Error> {
    Future<[Int],Error> { contination in
        Task {
            do {
                var items = try await service.getItems().value
                if items.isEmpty {
                    items = try await service.generateItems().value
                }

                contination(.success(items))
            } catch (let error) {
                contination(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I find this much more readable than the version using the subscription in the closure. To the outside world, `sync` uses the same `Futures` that are used in the service's API.

I did all this in a Playground and tested it with this code:

```
Task {
    do {
        let items = try await sync(service: Service(shouldReturnItems: true)).value
        print("service 1 returned \(items)")
    } catch {
        print("service 1 returned error")
    }
}

Task {
    do {
        let items = try await sync(service: Service(shouldReturnItems: false)).value
        print("service 2 returned \(items)")
    } catch {
        print("service 2 returned error")
    }
}
```

For iOS 14 where the async `value` property of a future is not available you might be able to use a variation on the themes above:

```
extension Future {
    func myValue() async throws -> Output  {
        return try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation({ continuation in
            var subscription: AnyCancellable?

            subscription = self.sink {
                subscription?.cancel()
                subscription = nil;
                if case .failure(let error) = $0 {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            } receiveValue: {
                subscription?.cancel()
                subscription = nil;
                continuation.resume(returning: $0)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and at the call site:

```
if #unavailable(iOS 15) {
    await someFuture.myValue()
} else {
    await someFuture.value
}
```

(perhaps giving `myValue` a nicer name)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! The structured concurrency option feels much more like .NET and JS (my background before native app dev) hopefully I can use this throughout my views and helpers to switch more to async await for consuming API results.

Our app supports iOS 14 and upwards and I noticed .value is only supported 15 onwards,  any idea what the fallback block would need to look like without .value?

Comment: @MichaelHarper, I added a bit at the end of the answer with something I typed into the editor here... it may need some cleanup for the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! we've looked at our user stats and are able to bump our min version to 15x so this issue will go away :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to solve this. If you don't actually need to know when the job is finished, then you can make your `sync` return Void and do this:

```
func syncʹ() {
    service.getItems
        .flatMap { items in
            items.isEmpty
            ? anotherAPICall().map { items }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            : Just(items).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .sink {
            if case .failure(let error) = $0 {
                // handle failure
            }
        } receiveValue: { [weak  self] items in
            guard let self else { return }
            self.saveItems(items)
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

If you want sync to still tell you when it's done for some downstream process then something like this:

```
func sync() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    return service.getItems
        .flatMap { items in
            items.isEmpty
            ? anotherAPICall().map { items }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            : Just(items).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .flatMap { [unowned self] items in
            self.saveItemsʹ(items)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func saveItemsʹ(_ items: [Item]) -> Future<Void, Never> {
    Future { [unowned self] promise in
        self.saveItems(items)
        promise(.success(()))
    }
}
```

The flatMap (first one) will make the api call and emit it's value (or error) if the array is empty, otherwise it will just emit th array.

Another option if you want to break up the job into logical units:

```
func async() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    let items = service.getItems
        .share()

    let otherCall = items
        .filter { $0.isEmpty }
        .flatMap { _ in anotherAPICall() }

    return Publishers.Merge(
        otherCall.map { [] },
        items.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    )
    .flatMap { [unowned self] items in
        self.saveItemsʹ(items)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

The above gives each side effect it's own response object.